# Add class to the current element in the list in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have one list to show in the tabular structure and i am giving the checkbox for each list item for selection purpose. But i want to select the current element on click of the checkbox. I tried with the ng-class thing but it is selecting all the list on click of one checkbox. Below is my code please check.

**list.html**

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys |  filter:global.search">
                        <span class="checkbox" ng-click="Click()" ng-class="checked"></span>
                        <div class="toogleSurvey row" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2  col-md-3">{{survey.SurveyName}}</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-4 hidden-xs">{{survey.Date | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'}}</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
$rootScope.Click = function(){
  $rootScope.surveySelected = !$rootScope.surveySelected;
  if($rootScope.surveySelected){
    $rootScope.checked = 'checked';
  }else{
    $rootScope.checked = '';
  }
};
```

in this on click of the one checkbox the 'checked' class is getting added to all the element in the ng-repeat. Using jquery we can  do this by using "this" keyword and we can traverse the DOM. So how to do it in angularjs?

Below is the snapshot of the work before and after click

**beforeclick**
[image]

**afterclick**
[image]

this checked class is getting added in all the list on click of the one ckeckbox

Showing the other elements based on the checked status.

**header.html**

```
<div class="navbar-header col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ng-show="surveySelected">
                <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left col-xs-2" ng-click="" id="backButton"></a>
                <span class="moduleTitle">Back</span>
          </div>
```

Modified list.html

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys |  filter:global.search">
                        <span class="checkbox" ng-click="surveySelected=!surveySelected" ng-class="{'checked':surveySelected}"></span>
                        <div class="toogleSurvey row" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2  col-md-3">{{survey.SurveyName}}</div>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys |  filter:global.search">
    <span class="checkbox" ng-click="survey.checked=!survey.checked" ng-class="{'checked':survey.checked}"></span>
        <div class="toogleSurvey row" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2  col-md-3">{{survey.SurveyName}}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-4 hidden-xs">{{survey.Date | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'}}</div>
            ...
```

Just set `survey.checked` on click and set class depending on it: `ng-class="{'checked':survey.checked}"`

P.s. and never ever use $rootScope like this. :)

Comment: I have to get the checked status outside the controller that is why i used $rootScope. Is there any way to get the checked status in another controller ? Bcoz i want to show some thing based on the checked status.

Comment: Well, why not to communicate between controllers via service? Anyway, there is no excuses to use $rootScope like this. Why not to wrap it in controller!?

Comment: Btw, my solution should work in any ways. Has it controller or not. You just storing checked state in data object.

Comment: it worked for the adding checked class. But it is not showing other element based on the checked status. I am posting my other codes for showing the data. Please check it is correct or not ...

Comment: surveySelected=!surveySelected - this is wrong. You're missing the main idea here. Store all changes in your data source. Not in the global variable. `survey.checked=!survey.checked`. Not `surveySelected=!surveySelected`. `survey.checked` - local property, `surveySelected` - global property.

Comment: i initialize this like $rootScope.surveySelected = false; It is working for adding the individual checked class. But if want this surveySelected status outside the controller then i have to make it global no ?

Comment: Can you create Plunker? I'll fix it to working state then.

Comment: Ok i am creating the plunker